# Creating a NFS sidecar for Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to create a NFS sidecar for Kubernetes.  The goal is to be able to mount an NFS volume to an existing pod without affecting performance.  At the same time, I want to be able to mount the same NFS volume onto another pod or server (read-only perhaps) in order to view the content there.  Has anyone tried this?  Do anyone have the procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use a sidecar I would suggest using a `PersistentVolume` which uses the NFS driver and `PersistentVolumeClaim`. If you use the `RWX`/`ReadWriteMany` access mode, you'll be able to mount the share into multiple pods.

For examplen the `pv`:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mypv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  nfs:
    server: my.nfs.server
    path: /myshare
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
```

the `pvc`:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: myclaim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
```

and mounted in a `pod`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: myfrontend
      image: nginx
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: "/var/www/html"
        name: mypd
  volumes:
    - name: mypd
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: myclaim
```

[Kubernetes Docs on Persistent Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/)